# Powershell Script to Update AWS Security Groups Based Upon Dynamic IP Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-vpc

I created a Powershell script that would run  in Task Scheduler to update my AWS security groups based upon my public ip address. When I run this script I get an error message which is posted below.

I would also like your help in modifying the script below to delete the old IP address when updating to the new IP address.

**The script**

```
# to get current ip address in cidr format 

$ipinfo = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json

$ipinfo.ip | out-file -filepath currentip -NoNewline

$ipCidr = Add-Content -Path "currentip" -Value "/32"     

# take current ip address and update the security group 
# the second part I am getting an error message pasted below 

$ipchange =  @{ IpProtocol="tcp"; FromPort="1433"; ToPort="1433"; IpRanges=$ipCidr}

Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-0d28d1cbc04d5df91 -Region us-east-2 -IpPermission @($ipchange)
```

**Error**

> <# Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress : Cannot bind parameter
>   'IpPermission'. Cannot create object of type
>   "Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission". Object of type
>   'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. At
>   C:\users\inayet\desktop\aws-amazon\scripts\runCurrentIP.ps1:15 char:93
>   + ... pId sg-0d28d1cbc04d5df91 -Region us-east-2 -IpPermission @($ipchange)
>   +                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.GrantEC2SecurityGroupIngressCmdlet
>   #>

Answer (score 0):

To address the type cast error message add this code just below the add-content line.

$ipCidr = $ipCidr -as [int]

What you are saying is that you want the string value stored in $ipCidr to be converted into integer value.

Now Another problem arises is that the variable $ipCidr = Add-Content -Path "currentip" -Value "/32" -NoNewline
does not output a value.

when I cat currentip I get the correct ip cidr address but when I output the value of $ipCidr the file is empty and I get the following error message "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

how do I store the integer value stored in currentip file to the variable $ipCidr ?

Answer (score 0):

That error message seems to say that the cmdlet `Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress` was expecting an object of type `Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission` and it could not construct one from the arguments you passed.

One line is suspect in your code that might explain the error:

```
$ipCidr = Add-Content -Path "currentip" -Value "/32"
```

Nothing is returned by `Add-Content`, which only adds lines to files, so `$ipCidr` contains nothing at this point.

You may want to try

```
$ipCidr = Get-Content -path "currentip"
```

before you continue to populate the hashtable:

```
$ipchange =  @{ IpProtocol="tcp"; FromPort="1433"; ToPort="1433"; IpRanges=$ipCidr}
```

The array syntax `@()` you placed around `$IpRanges` is not necessary, either, and is probably also a major contributor to the error message you're receiving.

```
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-0d28d1cbc04d5df91 -Region us-east-2 -IpPermission $ipchange
```

Now that the `IpRanges` member is no longer empty, powershell may be able to make the conversion to `Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I made changes to the code based upon your feedback but still getting error messages, I will post the revised code in another comment

Comment: Better to modify your question with progress

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for contributing!!!

Here is a solution to the problem I was encountering.

`# to get current ip address in cidr format`

`$ipinfo = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json`

`$ipinfo.ip +"/32" | out-file -filepath currentip -NoNewline`

`$ipCidr = Get-Content -Path currentip`

`$ipchange = @{ IpProtocol="tcp"; FromPort="1433"; ToPort="1433"; IpRanges=$ipCidr} $ipchange`

`Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-123456789 -Region us-east-2 -IpPermission $ipchange`